# Cannot install Adventure Works DB to Sql Server because Install Instance drop down is blank

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to install the Adventure Works database onto an instance of SQL Server but i cannot get any instance entries listed in the dialog as below:

[image]

I have enabled FileStream and TextIndexing is installed.
This is a 64 bit Sql Server Instance running on 64 bit Windows 7.
Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Is your SQLBrowser service running? The SQL-instance can't be detected if that's not running.

Comment: Yes SqlBrowser service is on.

Comment: Are you sure that you installed the Database Engine component when you installed SQL?

Comment: Yes the server instance contains other dbs.

Answer (score 1):

You should have "Windows Authentication" enabled and also your current "Windows Account" name should have access to your SQL Server instance. Because there is no question about the login info in the installer (damn it!) so default info would be your windows account information.

Answer (score 0):

Open SQL  server management studio, expand security and logins, right clcik your credential and click properties.From the login properties click **server roles** and make sure that your credential have sysadmin permission(sysadmin check-box is checked).

[image]